Select items in list where attribute does *not* match regex pattern
I have a list of dicts, something like:
[
  {
    "url": "bucket.amazonaws.com",
    "file": "file1.txt"
  },
  {
    "url": "github.com",
    "file": "file2.txt"
  }
]

I can filter the results to create a variable with files in AWS:
aws_files: "{{ array | selectattr('url', 'match', '.*amazonaws\\.com.*') }}"

Or files in Github:
github_files: "{{ array | selectattr('url', 'match', '.*github\\.com.*') }}"

How can I filter to find all files that don't match either of the above patterns?
This is what I have but I don't think it's right:
remaining_files: "{{ not (array | selectattr('url', 'match', '.*(amazonaws|github)\\.com.*')) }}"

This also doesn't work:
remaining_files: "{{ array | selectattr('url', 'notmatch', '.*(amazonaws|github)\\.com.*') }}"

Also, secondary question: is there a way to match the pattern anywhere in the string (so I don't have to always add .* to the beginning/end of the pattern).

Did you try rejectattr.

To your secondary question did you try using search instead of match? I believe you could also use in.

For example, given the patterns in a list
  patterns:
    - .*amazonaws\.com.*
    - .*github\.com.*

and the array for testing
  array:
    - {file: file1.txt, url: bucket.amazonaws.com}
    - {file: file2.txt, url: github.com}
    - {file: file3.txt, url: example.com}

Select the aws and github files
  aws_files: "{{ array | selectattr('url', 'match', patterns.0) }}"
  github_files: "{{ array | selectattr('url', 'match', patterns.1) }}"

gives
  aws_files: [{'file': 'file1.txt', 'url': 'bucket.amazonaws.com'}]
  github_files: [{'file': 'file2.txt', 'url': 'github.com'}]

You can now subtract the matching lists
  result: "{{ array | difference(aws_files + github_files) }}"

to get what you want
  result: [{'file': 'file3.txt', 'url': 'example.com'}]

Or, you can reject joined patterns. The declaration below gives the same result
  result: "{{ array | rejectattr('url', 'match', patterns|join('|')) }}"



Example of a complete playbook for testing
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    patterns:
      - .*amazonaws\.com.*
      - .*github\.com.*

    array:
      - {file: file1.txt, url: bucket.amazonaws.com}
      - {file: file2.txt, url: github.com}
      - {file: file3.txt, url: example.com}

    aws_files: "{{ array | selectattr('url', 'match', patterns.0) }}"
    github_files: "{{ array | selectattr('url', 'match', patterns.1) }}"

    result: "{{ array | difference(aws_files + github_files) }}"
    resul2: "{{ array | rejectattr('url', 'match', patterns|join('|')) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          aws_files: {{ aws_files }}
          github_files: {{ github_files }}
          result: {{ result }}
          resul2: {{ resul2 }}


Note: You can simplify the patterns
  patterns:
    - amazonaws\.com
    - github\.com

and use search instead of match. The test match, quoting:

succeeds if it finds the pattern at the beginning of the string

but, the test search, quoting:

succeeds if it finds the pattern anywhere within the string



Thank you this fixed my issue. Is there a single place where I can find all available tests? For instance, I wouldn't have heard of the search test if you hadn't mentioned it. I haven't been able to find anywhere that just has a full list of available tests that can be used.

There are Ansible tests and Jinja tests. In Ansible, each collection can provide tests. For example community.general tests.
